# How can I create a list with one element but with a given depth?

Tags: list, functional-programming, racket, nested-lists

I'm new in racket and I want to find the way to create a list with only one element but with a given depth by recursion. For example:

```
> (create-list 3 'x)
'(((x)))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a list with a single element nested n levels deep:

- if n is zero the answer is the element (it's not nested any levels deep);
- otherwise assume n > 0, and then create a single element list whose element is the result of creating a list with a single element nested n - 1 levels deep, which function you will need to write ... unless, perhaps you just have?

The function that creates a list is `list` so to create a single element list you use `(list e)` where `e` is the element.